# create 6 checkboxes in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I create 6 checkboxes that will look like this?  I know how to hide the check box, but how can I make is so I can click the text?

```
<tr>
<td class = "first">Select Folder(s)</td>
<td class = "second">
<input id="hw" type="checkbox">hw1
  <input id="hw" type="checkbox">hw2
     <input id="hw" type="checkbox">hw3
        <input id="hw" type="checkbox">hw4
           <input id="hw" type="checkbox">hw5
              <input id="hw" type="checkbox">hw6
</td>
```

It should be like this:

Select Foler | (hw1) (hw2) .....

and the hw checkboxes should be clickable, and I need to be able to select more than one.

Comment: Wrap the input and text in a label element.

Comment: I think you are looking for `<label>` elements that can associate text with an input. Btw, your ids need to be unique.

Comment: You are looking for poor usability. If you hide the checkboxes, the user does not see what he has selected. If you intend to overcome this in CSS, you should show the CSS code, since it essentially affects the issue.

Comment: Same Id not allowed in a page

Answer (score 9):

I think you want the `<label>` HTML tag.  You specify the `<label` then `for="` then the `id` of the element that you want to attach it to (a radio or checkbox).  In the end, it should look something like this:

`<label for="hw">text that they can click on goes here</label>`

As stated by @tieTYT in the comments, an alternative way to do this would be to wrap the `<label>` tag around the radio or checkbox element like this:

`<label><input type="radio"/>Text for the label here</label>`

Note: *You may still need to add the `for=` attribute for old and buggy IE browsers.*

Here's your final code (I added the CSS property `cursor:pointer;` to the `<label>`s):

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="first">Select Folder(s)</td>
  <td class="second">
    <input id="hw" type="checkbox">
    <label for="hw">hw1</label>
    <input id="hw2" type="checkbox">
    <label for="hw2">hw2</label>
    <input id="hw3" type="checkbox">
    <label for="hw3">hw3</label>
    <input id="hw4" type="checkbox">
    <label for="hw4">hw4</label>
    <input id="hw5" type="checkbox">
    <label for="hw5">hw5</label>
    <input id="hw6" type="checkbox">
    <label for="hw6">hw6</label>
  </td>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `for` attribute if you wrap the label around the `input`.

Comment: Thank you.  Didn't know that, and I'm learning something new every day!

Comment: @tieTYT—except for buggy versions of IE of course which require *for* attributes regardless…

Comment: +1 for `cursor:pointer;`. Somehow I never thought about using that for a `<label>`.

Comment: why don't you use a loop?   for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++) {echo "<input id='".${'hw'.$i}."' type="checkbox"><label for='".${'hw'.$i}."'>".${'hw'.$i}."</label>";

Comment: Why would I do that, @datelligent?  That's not what the question was about.  AT ALL.

Comment: @tieTYT Is that according to the spec, or just nice browser people?